# Building cell reference to another file from cell values

Tags: excel, file, reference, cell

I'm not sure if this is even possible. I need to make references to cells in multiple other Excel files.

To make it simple: I can get the data I require with the following string, in Sheet1 of my workbook:

```
=SUM('C:\Folder\[Person''s Tracker.xls]April 2014'!$A$1:$A$54)"
```

It's referencing another workbook to `SUM` tracking data.

However, I want to dynamically build this string using cell references from another sheet:

- "C:\Folder\" is stored as text in Sheet2, cell C5.
- "[Person''s Tracker.xls]" is stored as text in Sheet 2, cell D5.
- "April 2014" is stored as text in Sheet 2, cell E5.

I've tried various combinations of `CONCATENATE` and `INDIRECT` but always end up with an error. Any ideas?

Comment: are the files closed? `INDIRECT()` doesnt work with closed files. See [various ways to pull data out of workbooks](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/various-ways-to-pull-data-from-another-workbook-closedopened/)

Answer (score 2):

Managed to sort it with the help of "me how".

Essentially, used `CONCATENATE` to string the file path and sheet name together in between to single quotes, inside an `INDIRECT` function which added the cell reference to the end.

E.g: `=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'", A1, A2, A3,"'!") & $C$2:$C$19))`